# Cannot run third party app on a particular computer

Tags: internet-explorer

We have several computers in our office, all running XP Pro. We use a third party, web survey application to screen questionnaires and they have to run in IE. On one particular computer, there is a functionality in the program that will not work.

In the questionnaire, one question has a series of answers that have check boxes and a none of the above box as well. Checking the none of the above box should clear out all the other answers. On this particular computer it does not.

I uninstalled Yahoo toolbar, upgraded to IE 8 and the functionality still does not work. It works on all the other computers in the office.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Activate JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.isjavascriptenabled.com/  Yes or no?

Comment: Thank you, kindly. It was a javascript issue. I needed to reset the regsvr32 javascript.dll in order to get it to work, since doing it through the Internet Options did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: I wonder what would have caused it to not work via Internet Options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you pay for this 3rd-party product? If so, I'd first talk to them and see what they say. It's their product, they should support it. Failing that, if you can I'd re-install that machine with an known "good" base system image if you have one. If you that's not an option, check version numbers for IE and for Windows and check that they all match up, try to get the Bad machine to match the good ones if possible. Also maybe run a malware/virus/spyware scan. This sounds like a JavaScript issue but without access to source code I don't know what else to recommend.

---

Yeah, that guy who said to activate JavaScript might be right. I guess I just assumed it was already active. Do other JavaScript pages give you problems on this computer?